# Comparing Two Datasets - Slow

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, collections

I have a set of data in the following format, although very simplified:

- DealerName, AccountCode, Value
- Dealer1, A-1, 5
- Dealer2, A-1, 10
- Dealer1, A-2, 20
- Dealer2, A-2, 15
- Dealer3, A-3, 5

I am trying to achieve an end result that gives me the data summed by AccountCode, so the following in the case of the above data:

- AccountCode, Value
- A-1, 15
- A-2, 35
- A-3, 5

I have done this by creating an array of distinct account codes named `OutputData` and then going through the data comparing the account code to the same field in `SelectedDealerData` and adding it to the existing values:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(SelectedDealerData)
    For j = 0 To UBound(OutputData)
        If SelectedDealerData(i).AccountNumber = OutputData(j).AccountNumber And SelectedDealerData(i).Year = OutputData(j).Year Then
            OutputData(j).Units = OutputData(j).Units + SelectedDealerData(i).Units
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

There are around 10,00 dealers and 600-1000 account codes for each, so this means a lot of unnecessary looping.

Can someone point me in the direction of a more efficient solution? I am thinking that some kind of Dictionary compare but I am unsure how to implement it.

Comment: Is this in Excel / Access? If it's in Excel, why not just use a worksheet function like `=SUMIFS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* for a Dictionary:

```
    Dim aggregated As Dictionary
    Set aggregated = New Dictionary

    For i = 0 To UBound(SelectedDealerData)
        With SelectedDealerData(i)
            If aggregated.Exists(.AccountCode) Then
                aggregated(.AccountCode) = aggregated(.AccountCode) + .Value
            Else
                aggregated(.AccountCode) = .Value
            End If
        End With
    Next

    For Each Key In aggregated.Keys
        Debug.? Key, aggregated(Key)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is slow because there are 10 million comparisons and assignment operations going on here (10,000 x 1000).

Also, looping through collections is not very efficient, but nothing can be done about that since the design is already set and maintained the way it is.

Two ways you can make this more efficient (you can time your code right now and see the % savings after these steps).

1. There are two condition-checks going on with an `And`. VBA will evaluate both even if the first one is false (no short circuiting). So put nested `if then` conditions, so that if the first condition fails, you do not proceed to checking the second one. Also, keep the condition more likely to fail in the outer `if` statement (so it fails fast and moves to the next element). At best, you get a minor speed bump here, at worst, you are no worse off.
2. There are too many comparisons happening here. Too late to change that, but you can go through the loops based on the following pseudocode if you can sort your collections or build an index which maintains their sort order (save that index array on your spreadsheet if you like). The sorting should be done based on a composite field called Account_Number_Year (just concatenate them)
3. You can use this concatenated field in the dictionary structure suggested by Alex K. So you can lookup this joint field in the second dictionary and then do operations if needed.

Code to try to fully implement it in VBA:

```
'Assuming both arrays are sorted
For i = 0 to Ni
    MatchingIndex = _
        BinarySearchForAccNumberYear(SelectedUserData(i).AccountNumberYear)
Next i
```

You can look up Binary Search [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

This will reduce your time complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log n) and your code will run an order of magnitude faster.